# How to move bone to the object position?

Tags: objects, bones

I made a simple sphere and a bone. I want to place a bone in the center of the sphere.

I want to just place it, not bind or constraint.

I don't want to change the rotation and scale of the bone

What should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to:

- Switch to object mode
- Select the sphere
- Object -> Snap -> Cursor to Selected
- Select the bone/armature
- Object -> Snap -> Selection to Cursor

This will move the entire armature so its origin is at the center of the sphere.

If you want to move the bone without affecting the armature origin (or if you have a multi-bone armature and only want to move one bone), then:

- As above, set the cursor to the sphere's origin.
- After selecting the armature, switch to edit mode and select the target bone.
- If there are multiple bones in armature, make sure the target bone is disconnected (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> -> Disconnect Bone)
- Armature -> Snap -> Selection to Cursor